# My plumber installed my hot water baseboard backward. The feed and return are hooked up backward. What problems will this cause?

Tags: water, heater, baseboard

I believe my hot water baseboard heater was hooked up wrong. The feed and return are opposite. The plumber said it's not a problem as we'll still get heat. Is that so, because we don't get a lot of heat from the heater. Please advise.

Comment: What makes you think the baseboard has feed and return? Every baseboard(as well as radiator) I've ever seen in a forced hot water system couldn't care less how it's connected. If it was just installed and doesn't heat up, the it is probably air bound and needs to be bled. Have the plumber come back and double check for that

Comment: Are you saying the bleeder vent should be on the feed side?
We are having similar issues and the heating tech agrees, it shouldn't matter which way the water flows. But each radiator's bleeder vent is not on the same side-feed or return. I don;t know if there is a one way "T" installed to direct the hot water up the feed then another to return to the loop.
I need to bleed air out of the same but not all radiators weekly.
Confused…
Ted

Comment: There will often be one spot that collects most of the air, whether by design or by accident will vary with the design or lack thereof. On the other hand, if you have to bleed every week, something is wrong - The fluid in the system should stay in the system, and once the air is removed, no new air should get in, with a properly functioning system. Constant air bleeding implies air leaking in or water leaking out (and being replaced by new water with new dissolved air.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a hot-water baseboard heater, there should be no problem from which way the water goes. It's a rather simple machine (pipe with heat dissipators) so it couldn't care less which direction the hot water is flowing.

What could be an issue is if a bleeder valve was installed on the output side and not the intake side. Typically the intake side would collect more air to bleed.